# ffmpeg overlay x expression with logical condition

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a simple overlay graphic where the overlay moves and screen and changes speed according to time. So I tried a simple

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vcodec qtrle -i overlay.mov -filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]overlay=x=if(t<2\,t*3\,t*5)[out]' -map '[out]' -y output.mp4

and got an error code of :

[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0000003f4e1e2ea0] [Eval @ 0000003f4c0fe5b0] Missing ')' or too many args in 'if(t<2,t*3,t*5)'

[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0000003f4e1e2ea0] Error when evaluating the expression 'if(t<2,t*3,t*5)' for x

[Parsed_overlay_0 @ 0000003f4e1e2ea0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_overlay_0

Error configuring complex filters.

Invalid argument

if I remove the "if" part and just leave a formula it works :

-filter_complex '[0:0][1:0]overlay=x=12+t*3[out]'

I tried playing with escaping of the different characters but it doesn't look like its a parsing error. Any ideas of how to use this correctly? The ffmpeg documentation has a sample for doing font color expression with a logical value [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Examples-80) , but any attempt at

overlay=x_expr

doesn't really work as well

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FFmpeg uses functions, rather than operators, for conditional execution and comparisons, so `t<2` is not a valid syntax.

The syntax for your given command would be

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i overlay.mov -filter_complex \
       "[0][1]overlay=x=if(lt(t\,2)\,t*3\,t*5)[out]" \
       -map '[out]' -c:v qtrle -y output.mp4
```

where `lt(var,value)` is the `less than` function.

Comment: Sure. How did your earlier project - drawtext - go?

Comment: hehe nice that you remembered. We ended doing a fade in fade out on the text,  the character by character thing didn't work out. And we ended doing everything in house...not much ffmpeg available for out sourcing.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how to crop landscape videos to square (1:1 aspect), while **not** cropping portrait videos:

`-filter_complex "[0:v]crop='if(lt(in_h,in_w),in_h,in_w):in_h'[out]"`

Comment: The Q isn't about cropping videos !?

Comment: The question is about using logical conditions in FFMPEG - so this is yet another example that people may find useful

Comment: This a Q and A site, not a wiki, so the As are supposed to be As for the Q posted.

Comment: I actually found it much useful